# Django Migrations Add Field with Default as Function of Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I added a new, non-nullable field to my Django model and am trying to use migrations to deploy that change. How would I set default value to use for existing models to be some function of those models rather than a constant?

As an example let's say I previously had a `created_on` field and I just added an `updated_on` field whose value I want to set initially to the model's `created_on`. How would I do this in a migration?

This is what I am trying to start with:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='series',
    name='updated_as',
    field=models.DateTimeField(default=????, auto_now=True),
    preserve_default=False,
),
```

Answer (score 153):

I just learned how to do this with a single migration!

When running `makemigrations` django should ask you to set a one-off default. Define whatever you can here to keep it happy, and you'll end up with the migration `AddField` you mentioned.

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='series',
    name='updated_as',
    field=models.DateTimeField(default=????, auto_now=True),
    preserve_default=False,
),
```

Change this one operation into 3 operations:

1. Initially make the field nullable, so the column will be added.
2. Call a function to populate the field as needed.
3. Alter the field (with `AlterField`) to make it not nullable (like the above, with no default).

So you end up with something like:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='series',
    name='updated_as',
    field=models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True),
),
migrations.RunPython(set_my_defaults, reverse_func),
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='series',
    name='updated_as',
    field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
),
```

with your functions defined as something like:

```
def set_my_defaults(apps, schema_editor):
    Series = apps.get_model('myapp', 'Series')
    for series in Series.objects.all().iterator():
        series.updated_as = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=series.some_other_field)
        series.save()

def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    pass  # code for reverting migration, if any
```

Except, you know, not terrible.

Note: Consider using [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/) and/or [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/) to increase migration performance for large databases.

Comment: you can use:
    Series.objects.all().update(updated_as=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=series.some_other_field)) #update works as a single request

Comment: Instead of `reverse_func`, you should use `migrations.RunPython.noop`. Check docs for further details - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython.noop

Comment: is it possible to obtain a similar dynamic value from a function, in the prompt asking for a default value? The prompt does mention that
> Please enter the default value now, as valid Python

Comment: @Fusion or you can omit the second argument if you don't want the migration to be reversible https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/writing-migrations/#id6

Answer (score 25):

You need to do it in two migrations. First of all, add your field, but make nullable. Create a migration file as usual. After that set your field to not-nullable and run makemigrations again, but don't lauch migrate yet. Open the second migration and define a function at the top:

```
def set_field_values(apps, schema_editor):
    # use apps.get_model("app_name", "model_name") and set the defualt values
```

then, in your migration file there is a list of operations. **Before** the alter field operation add

```
RunPython(set_field_values)
```

and it should do it

Answer (score 10):

You should also define a reverse for your function `set_my_defaults()`, in case you what to revert the migration in the future.

```
def reverse_set_default(apps, schema_editor):
    pass
```

The reverse function in this case need to do nothing, since you are removing the field.

And add it to RunPython:

```
migrations.RunPython(set_my_defaults, reverse_set_default),
```

Comment: You should post this as a comment to @FraggaMuffin 's answer.

Comment: If you're just using a function with `pass`, you should use `migrations.RunPython.noop` instead. So `migrations.RunPython(set_my_defaults, migrations.RunPython.noop)`

Answer (score 1):

To add a default value taken from an existing field to a new non-nullable field, write your migration as follows:

- run makemigrations
- add `null=True` to the generated `AddField` statement
- add a [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) statement to populate the new field based on an existing field for all records in the table
- remove the `null=True` again with an `AlterField` statement

```py
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='series',
    name='updated_as',
    field=models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True),
),
migrations.RunSQL(
    sql="UPDATE myapp_series SET updated_as = created_on",
    reverse_sql=migrations.RunSQL.noop
),
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='series',
    name='updated_as',
    field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
),
```