# Django: Change settings value during run-time in migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I am trying to change a value in `settings.py` during run-time while creating migrations.

**settings.py:**

```
...
magicVar = "initValue"
```

**0002_init:**

```
...
def change_magicVar(apps, schema_editor):
    settings.magicVar = "newValue"
...

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(change_magicVar),
]
...
```

**0003_changed_migrations:**

```
...
def print_magicVar(apps, schema_editor):
   # Yay! It prints the correct value
   print (settings.magicVar) # prints: newValue
...

operations = [
   migrations.RunPython(print_magicVar),
   migrations.CreateModel(
     name='MagicModel',
        fields=[
            ('someMagic', 
               models.ForeignKey(
                  # Oops! This still has the old value, i.e *initValue*
                  # I want to achieve the *newValue* here!
                  default=settings.magicVar,
                  ... 
    )),
```

I want the changed value in migrations, but it looks like the value is already been cached.
Does django provide an abstraction to refresh the migrations cache and put a new value in it? If not, what possible options do i have to achieve that value in the defaults?

**Note:** I am trying to avoid [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40601025/6410464) because my database might give millions of records and iterating over them isn't ideal.

For external reasons i am also trying to avoid [django-livesettings](https://django-livesettings.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html)

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not achieve it this way. You can check https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance .

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. 
Also, thanks to Jason, who gave the same [response on mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/MIcuybPTqY0) :)