# Providing a static default value for a new field in existing objects in model?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I have a model that has 10000 objects and I want to add a new field to it that equals the result of a function acting on another field

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    new_field = models.CharField(max_length=255,default=my_func(self.field1))
```

how can I achieve this? to provide a default value for every object in my DB based upon one of its fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Migrations Add Field with Default as Function of Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787853/django-migrations-add-field-with-default-as-function-of-model)

Comment: thanks for your help this is what i needed.

Comment: i flagged the question.